# Joining portions of a python dictionary using a reference dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, join

I have a dictionary of dataframes with keys that look like this.  It's called frames1.

```
dict_keys(['TableA','TableB','TableC','TableD'])
```

I also have a 'master' dataframe that tells me how to join these dataframes.

| Gold Table | Silver Table 1 | Silver Table 2 | Join Type | Left_Attr | Right_Attr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| System | Table A | Table B | left | ID | applic_id |
| System | Table C | Table A | right | fam | famid |
| System | Table A | Table D | left | NameID | name |

The "System" gold table is the combination of all 3 rows.  In other words, I need to join Table A to Table B on the attributes listed and then use that output as my NEW Table A when I join Table C and Table A in row 2.  Then I need to use that table to as my NEW Table A to join to Table D. This creates the final "System" Table.

What I've tried:

```
for i in range(len(master)):
     System = pd.merge(frames1[master.iloc[i,1]],frames1[master.iloc[i,2]], how=master.iloc[i,3], on_left= master.iloc[i,4],on_right=master.iloc[i,5])
```

This only gets me one row which will then over write the other rows as it goes on.  How would I go about creating a for loop to join these together?

Comment: The code should actually not do anything as the returned merged frame isn't stored.

Comment: I've updated to show the name of the desired output df.

Comment: The `System` df must either appear directly as a df in the `merge` call or must be set as a value in the `frames1` dict. According to your description table A is always replaced by the result, so it would be `frames1['A'] = System`.

Comment: by the way, does anyone know when pandas merge started accepting dictionaries as arguments?  What version? This code above works in Pandas 1.5.2 but not 1.2.4.